# Null pointer exception when using Mockito to mock interface

Tags: java, unit-testing, nullpointerexception, mockito

I'm using Mockito to test the following method:

```java
  protected void produceProducedFieldValue(Target target) throws ValueProducerCreationException {
    String mappedValue = (String) valueProducerFactory.createValueProducer("IdProducer", Collections.emptyList()).get();
    target.setProducedField(mappedValue);
  }
```

Here is my test:

```java
     @Test
    public void TestProducingProducedFieldValue() throws ValueProducerCreationException {

        Target mockedTarget = Mockito.mock(Target.class);
        ValueProducerFactory valueProducerFactory = Mockito.mock(ValueProducerFactory.class);
        List<Object> creationParameters = new ArrayList<>();

        String mappedValue= "SomeString";

        Mockito.when(valueProducerFactory.createValueProducer("IdProducer", Collections.emptyList()).get()).thenReturn(mappedValue);
        SourceToTargetMapper sttm = new SourceToTargetMapper(targetModelObjectFactory,mappingOperatorFactory,mapperFactory,valueProducerFactory);
        sttm.produceProducedFieldValue(mockedTarget);
        Mockito.verify(mockedTarget, Mockito.times(1)).setProducedField(Mockito.any());
    }
```

But I keep getting `NullPointerExeption` for this line:

```java
    Mockito.when(valueProducerFactory.createValueProducer("IdProducer", Collections.emptyList()).get()).thenReturn(mappedValue);
```

`ValueProducerFactory` is an Interface

and the `createValueProducer` method signature is as follows:

```java
    public interface ValueProducerFactory {

        <T> Supplier<T> createValueProducer(String producerName, List<Object> creationParameters) throws ValueProducerCreationException;

    }
```

I have a class named CachingValueProducerFactory that implements the interface

```java
    @Override
    public <T> Supplier<T> createValueProducer(String producerName, List<Object> creationParameters) throws ValueProducerCreationException {
        Map<List<Object>, Supplier<?>> parametersToOperatorsMap = producersCache.computeIfAbsent(producerName, s -> new HashMap<>());

        List<Object> key = Optional.ofNullable(creationParameters).orElse(Collections.emptyList());

        if (!parametersToOperatorsMap.containsKey(key)) {
            parametersToOperatorsMap.put(key, nestedProducersFactory.createValueProducer(producerName, creationParameters));
        }

        return (Supplier<T>) parametersToOperatorsMap.get(key);
    }
```

It seems like using `Collections.emptyList()` in the test is the problem, but I don't see any other solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to mock two methods at once. In this line:

```
Mockito.when(valueProducerFactory.createValueProducer("IdProducer", Collections.emptyList()).get()).thenReturn(mappedValue);
```

you are calling `get()` on the result of the `createValueProducer()` call, which is `null` because you haven't mocked it yet.

There are two solutions:

**Use deep stubbing**:

```java
ValueProducerFactory valueProducerFactory = Mockito.mock(ValueProducerFactory.class, Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
Mockito.when(valueProducerFactory.createValueProducer("IdProducer", Collections.emptyList()).get()).thenReturn(mappedValue);
```

**Mock the Supplier first** (pay attention to the removed `get()`):

```
Supplier<Object> supplier = () -> mappedValue;
ValueProducerFactory valueProducerFactory = Mockito.mock(ValueProducerFactory.class);
Mockito.when(valueProducerFactory.createValueProducer("IdProducer", Collections.emptyList())).thenReturn(supplier);
```